# Hardware-accelerated Bing Maps... not accelerated?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, bing-maps, hardware-acceleration

In my SL4 application I add a lot of `Polyline` objects onto a Bing Map control. The end result is that the application is sluggish when, for example, moving the map.

Thus, I've tried enabling GPU acceleration.

I've added an extra parameter to the .aspx page hosting the SL application:

```
      <param name="EnableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />
```

I've also added the following bit of XAML code to the map control:

```
            <bing:Map.CacheMode>
                <BitmapCache/>
            </bing:Map.CacheMode>
```

Unfortunately, it's still just as slow as before. Did I forget about something? Or does it mean Bing Maps won't benefit from GPU acceleration?

Comment: Perhaps you have the permission denied? Right click on your Silverlight app and go into the settings to make sure the user (you in this case) has Hardware Acceleration allowed. Just a guess.

Comment: While I wish it were this easy, sadly, it's not. The option is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware acceleration won't help when you have a lot of polyline's/polygon's. Here are two tools for getting good performance with the Bing Maps Silverlight controls:

http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2010/11/19/optimize-map-layers-in-bing-maps-silverlight/
http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2010/03/06/multipolygon-multilinestring-classes-for-bing-maps-silverlight/

Using these two pieces of code I'm able to render 95mb of polygon data without any performance issue.